# Trait to optionally dereference a reference to a Copy object?

Tags: rust, iterator, traits, ref

I'm implementing a function that takes a list of elements by value, but I'll need to perform two passes over the list.  The first pass computes some value over the input data (without modifying the input data), and the second pass consumes the input data.

Essentially, something like this:

```
fn make_from_elements<K, V, C>(elements: C) -> Container<K, V>
where
    K: Copy + Ord,
    C: IntoIterator<Item = (K, V)>,
    for<'a> &'a C: IntoIterator<Item = (&'a K, &'a V)>,
{
    let max_key = (&elements).into_iter().map(|(k, v)| *k).max().unwrap();
    make_container(max_key, elements)
}
```

However, the above code assumes that `(&elements).into_iter().map(|(k, v)| k)` is an iterator whose item type is `&K`.  This is not always true for some special containers I have; sometimes, the above expression is an iterator whose item type is `K` (without the reference).  Is there a trait that wraps possibly referenced objects that implement `Copy`?

In other words, I'm trying to find something that should work like this:

```
fn make_from_elements<K, V, C, Q>(elements: C) -> Container<K, V>
where
    K: Copy + Ord,
    C: IntoIterator<Item = (K, V)>,
    for<'a> &'a C: IntoIterator<Item = (Q + 'a, &'a V)>,
    Q: MaybeDerefCopy<K>,
{
    let max_key = (&elements).into_iter().map(|(k, v)| k.maybe_deref_copy()).max().unwrap();
    make_container(max_key, elements)
}
```

How can I do such a thing in Rust?

Answer (score 2):

The [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) trait should work here, as both `T` and `&T` implement `Borrow<T>`.

```
fn make_from_elements<KR, K, V, C>(elements: C) -> Container<K, V>
where
    K: Copy + Ord,
    KR: Borrow<K>,
    C: IntoIterator<Item = (KR, V)>,
    for<'a> &'a C: IntoIterator<Item = (&'a KR, &'a V)>,
{
    let max_key = (&elements).into_iter().map(|(k, v)| *k.borrow()).max().unwrap();
    make_container(max_key, elements)
}
```

Also you can make your function support more types by requiring `Clone` instead of `Copy`.  The `Clone` implementation for `Copy` types should already delegate to a simple bitwise copy, which should get inlined anyway, so for `Copy` types performance would be unaffected.

```
fn make_from_elements<KR, K, V, C>(elements: C) -> Container<K, V>
where
    K: Clone + Ord,
    KR: Borrow<K>,
    C: IntoIterator<Item = (KR, V)>,
    for<'a> &'a C: IntoIterator<Item = (&'a KR, &'a V)>,
{
    let max_key = (&elements)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(k, v)| k.borrow().clone())
        .max()
        .unwrap();
    make_container(max_key, elements)
}
```

Comment: I think it should be just `KR` instead of `&'a KR`?

Comment: I was about to respond about making your own trait but using `Borrow` is better.

Comment: @Bernard Unlikely, unless you're writing your own iterators. E.g. if you have a `x: Vec<&T>` then iterating `&x` will produce a sequence of `&&T`.

Comment: No, in my question I said that `(&elements).into_iter().map(|(k, v)| k)` might yield elements of type `K`.  This is because my special container doesn't actually store keys; it computes them on the fly.

Comment: @Bernard Ah, well then, yes. Presumably you can change the types as appropriate given your environment.

Comment: It isn't obvious how to write `KR` without the reference though, because I can't specify the `'a` part of the possibly-reference type in the `Item = (KR, &'a V)` bit.

Comment: It does seem like we need to be able to write `for<'a> &'a C: IntoIterator<Item = (KR<'a>, &'a V)>, for<'a> KR<'a>: Borrow<K> + 'a`, which doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @Bernard There is a blanket `impl<T: Ord> Ord for &T` in the standard library, so the `max()` iterator invocation should work even with references, you'd just get a reference out the other end. So maybe all you'd really need is a way to clone any level of nested references into an owned value?

Comment: Yeah but that's not the problem.  The most difficult part of my question is not answered here - that I want to accept special containers that yield `K` by value, and also accept regular std containers that yield `K` by reference at the same time, and we need a way to express that as a trait bound.